latex template for IEEE transactions on computers
I want to submit a paper in IEEE transactions on computers : https://www.computer.org/digital-library/journals/tc/call-for-papers-general-submissions
I really don't understand from where should I download the latex template?
It would be really great help if someone can provide me the link to download the template.

not really a tex question but i guess https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/downloadTemplate?publicationTypeId=1&titleId=142&articleId=1&fileId=187

Thank you for great help @DavidCarlisle
